# how to Get thick signature using jSignature?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsignature

**Notes:** I tried all questions & answers related this topic. Additionally and I tried related questions and try to solve it but no the success. So please read my question thoroughly.

i am using ***[jSignature](https://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/demo/)*** . i want to Get thick Signature after Draw signature. I know set value `lineWidth` set value '2' or '3' but my requirement  draw Signature **`lineWidth : 1`** and get thick signature.

**i set `linewidth` 2 or 3 around then the signature is Draw is not Cleary some horizontal line are there. This Problem arise in IE**
[image]

**[JsFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/euu4d1n2/)**

**My Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#DrawSign-signature").jSignature({
     'decor-color': 'transparent',
     'color': '#000',
     'width': '400',
     'height': '160',
     'lineWidth': 1,
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/js/libs/jSignature.min.js"></script>
<div id="DrawSign-signature" style="border:1px solid black;width:400px;height:160px;">
     </div>
```

Comment: I tried with linewidth 2 and 3 on chrome and firefox doesn't seems the horizontal lines as you say / shown in red coloured circle,  I thing IE has some issues yet, this will work on Edge, update your browsers and then try.

Comment: ya . but i set linewidth 2 and 3 on chrome and firefox then the signature is a blur in upper and lower side, not cleary draw.

Comment: Which chrome version do you have?

Comment: I've this Version 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)